# .NET 6 LINQ DistinctBy not supported exception

Tags: c#, linq, .net-6.0

In my .NET 6,0 app I'm trying to use (new to .NET 6.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.distinctby?view=net-6.0) method DistinctBy, something like this:

```
return context.Table
    .Where(x => x.IsLive)
    .DistinctBy(x => x.Field1)
    .ToList();
```

Buld is fine, no errors, but at runtime I get this:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyType] DistinctBy[DbFundHistoPrice,String](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[VanEck.Repositories.Entities.Website.Funds.DbFundHistoPrice], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[VanEck.Repositories.Entities.Website.Funds.DbFundHistoPrice,System.String]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__1()
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__0()
     at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__31_0()
     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
     *my call here*
```

Other queries without new .NET 6 methods work fine (upgrading from 5 so there are some).

What am I missing here? Somethig in startup or in project settings?

I know that these extensions can be trimmed during build but I see no reason for that here since the method is actually used.

Comment: what provider of ef core you are using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are using older ORM (EF 6?) which does not support this method.

`DistinctBy` is not supported even by EF Core (which I recommend upgrading to) at the moment. See this issue - [*Translate LINQ DistinctBy*](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27470). You can try rewriting it with `GroupBy(e => e.Field1).Select(g => g.First())`.

See also:

- [Support new .NET LINQ features](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25570) issue